# Authenticate users based on condition rather than Auth System with Laravel Websockets/Echo?

Tags: php, laravel, chat, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I'm looking to create a chat system for an application of mine, an application where Authenticated users can create public or private events. I'm using Laravel Websockets and Laravel Echo. When I create a private channel and a user is not logged in, I get a 403 error, which is fine. The authentication or "handshake", is based off of Laravel's default Authentication system. Is it possible instead to allow/disallow access to the private channel using a condition, instead of Laravel's Auth system? For example weather a user with an ID exists in a different table, not the users table?

Let's say I have a table called `reg_users` (for registered users) for an event, with id of `ud4x7mw` in the URL, and I simply want to check weather the user with that ID exists or not, and if they do grant them access to the channel, if not deny them access. Would something like this be possible?

Comment: Are you still using the `users` table on different occasion?

Comment: In the table `reg_users`, do you have `user_id` there to be linked on the `users` table?

Comment: Yes Users table will be used for Admins of the platform. There's no user_id in the reg_users table, they are not linked in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you can add guard and provider for `reg_users` in `config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'reg_users' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'reg_users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    
    'reg_users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\RegUser::class,
    ],
],
```

Then in your `routes/channels.php` you can specify which guard are you using:

```
Broadcast::channel('SomeChannel', function ($user) {
    return true;
}, ['guards' => ['reg_users']]);
```